# Getting kibana dashboard body to embed in iframe trough spring boot backend instead of directly from kibana

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, iframe, spring-data-jpa, kibana

the general idea I want to implement is https://boringtechnology1.github.io/jekyll/update/2022/11/05/secured-kibana-dashboard-with-angular-and-spring-boot.html, but I have a few key differences:

1. I don't have kibana security enabled. This is personal project. No need for me to log in as far as I understand it.
2. I don't want to use nginx if possible

I simply want to pass the request from the frontend to kibana and back trough my backend. In my implementation I have an endpoint that takes the name of the dashboard and checks the database for the url to get the embbed content and then responds to the frontend with the response from kibana. My browser doesn't want to load it because of  x-frame options or a content security policy. for some reason x-Frame-Options are always set to deny.

my code is as follows:
this is the controller for the kibana request

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/kibana-dashboard/api/")
@AllArgsConstructor
//@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class KibanaDashboardController {

    private KibanaDashboardService kibanaDashboardService;

    @GetMapping("dashboard/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getDashboard(@PathVariable("name") String name) {


        return kibanaDashboardService.getDashboard(name).map(KibanaDashboardResponse::kibanaResponse)
                .orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                .build());
    }
```

KibanaDashboardResponse - this is just a wrapper for the response

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public record KibanaDashboardResponse(@NotNull ResponseEntity<String> kibanaResponse) {
}
```

entity class that contains the kibana dashboard url

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "kibana_dashboard")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class KibanaDashboard {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("kibana_url")
    private String KibanaUrl;
}
```

service to retrive kibana dashboard

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class KibanaDashboardServiceImpl implements KibanaDashboardService {

    private final KibanaDashboardRepository kibanaDashboardRepository;

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public KibanaDashboardServiceImpl(RestTemplateBuilder builder, KibanaDashboardRepository kibanaDashboardRepository1) {
        this.restTemplate = builder.build();
        this.kibanaDashboardRepository = kibanaDashboardRepository1;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<KibanaDashboardResponse> getDashboard(String name) {
        var kibanaDashboardUrl = kibanaDashboardRepository.findKibanaDashboardByNameIgnoreCase(name);
        var kibanaResponseBody = kibanaDashboardUrl.map(kibanaDashboard -> restTemplate.exchange(kibanaDashboard.getKibanaUrl(), HttpMethod.GET,
                HttpEntity.EMPTY, String.class));

        System.out.println(kibanaResponseBody);

        return kibanaResponseBody.map(KibanaDashboardResponse::new);
    }
```

}

the iframe

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:8080/kibana-dashboard/api/dashboard/test" height="600" width="800"></iframe>
```

I am pretty new to all of this and am trying to learn, so help would be appreciated.